# Using Winforms, how can I insert the value of a masked textbox into a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, maskedtextbox

I'm having trouble inserting the value of a masked textbox field into a database via a button click event.

I have a form that looks like this:

[Insert Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU6u4.png)

So basically you enter the data into the fields, click the button and it *should* Insert into the database using this code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open connection with the SQL Server, using connection string
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MY-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EnlaceDigital;User ID=user;Password=pass");
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Contratos VALUES ('" + this.teléfonoMaskedTextBox.Text + "', " +
            "'" + this.folio_PISATextBox.Text + "', '" + this.tipo_de_TareaTextBox.Text + "', " +
            "'" + this.estatusTextBox.Text + "','" + this.motivo_EstatusTextBox.Text + "','" + this.dTOTextBox.Text + "'," +
            "'" + this.cOPETextBox.Text + "','" + this.no__ExpedienteTextBox.Text + "'," +
            "'" + DateTime.Parse(this.fecha_InicialDateTimePicker.Text) + "', '" + DateTime.Parse(this.fecha_SolicitudDateTimePicker.Text) + "');", con);

        query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Added");
        con.Close();
        this.Close();
    }
```

However, this method grabs the .Text property of the fields, so the Masked Textbox (*field "Teléfono"*) writes the whole mask format into my database!

So in the database, I end up with something like "(012) 345 - 6789" instead of a 10 digit number.

I think this is happening because I'm basically inserting the content or **Text** of the textbox "as is", since I'm using `this.teléfonoMaskedTextBox.Text`, and I don't know how to get the actual **Value** of the field, and not just the **Text**.

If it helps, the field "Teléfono" is of type **nvarchar(50)**, so it "accepts" the mask format, but i need to insert into the database just the 10 digit phone number (without the mask), for other purposes.

Thank you.

Comment: You start by learning to use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: Apparently my question has been asked before, but I'll look into these topics, thank you!